# How to print output to Travis Every 5 mins

Tags: ansible, yaml, travis-ci

I have a travis CI build that keeps failing. The error is..

> The job exceeded the maximum log length, and has been terminated.

I googled possible reasons.. one of which is..

> ...If no output is received from a build for 10 minutes, it’s assumed to have stalled for unknown reasons and is subsequently killed.

So, to test if this is the actual error, I wanted to add a timer that logs an output every 5 minutes. I have never played with Ansible language before.

This is my current code..

```
before_script:
  - |
      - while sleep 5m; do echo "=====[ $SECONDS seconds, buildroot still building... ]====="
```

This is what I want to happen..
Following advice from this blog https://blog.humphd.org/building-large-code-on-travis/

```
=====[ 495 seconds, buildroot still building... ]=====
=====[ 795 seconds, buildroot still building... ]=====
=====[ 1095 seconds, buildroot still building... ]=====
=====[ 1395 seconds, buildroot still building... ]=====
=====[ 1695 seconds, buildroot still building... ]=====
=====[ 1995 seconds, buildroot still building... ]=====
=====[ 2295 seconds, buildroot still building... ]=====
=====[ 2595 seconds, buildroot still building... ]=====
=====[ 2895 seconds, buildroot still building... ]=====
```

Answer (score 1):

You could print to the output inside `.travis.yml` like so:

```
language: sh
before_script:
  - while travis_wait 50 sleep 300 &> /tmp/build.log || (tail -n 100 /tmp/build.log && exit 1); do echo "=====[ $SECONDS seconds, buildroot still building... ]====="; done
```

In this example we use the travis_wait function on a sleep command. To avoid printing internal stuff to the console, we print the output from travis_wait to a temporary log file if it succeeded otherwise we print the last 100 log lines and terminate with a status code of 1 before the actually output.